# Making the link button clicked default using Javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, href, linkbutton, click

I have a page which has six link buttons. when we open the page it shows the first link button default. I want to make the "showall" link button clicked default instead of "1"

code:

```
<div class="phonepager fcolrblk2c" adbe="handled">
         Page
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage1','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage1">1</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage2','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage2">2</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage3','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage3">3</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage4','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage4">4</a>&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPage5','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPage5">5</a>&nbsp;
 | <a style="display: none;" href="javascript:__doPostBack('pgrTop$lnkPageShowAll','')" id="pgrTop_lnkPageShowAll">See all on one page</a><span id="pgrTop_lblShowAll">See all on one page</span>&nbsp;
      </div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is a good solution. If you use that you could use this syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#pgrTop_lnkPageShowAll').focus();
});
```

If you're not using JQuery yet, pop this in your head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It is not working. Iwant to execute show all href instead of '1'.